# get string from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

trying to loop on string array but it throws error foreach is not a function what is correct way to implement using typescript ?

main.ts

```
content = ["renewel","payments"]
```

if i do for loop

```
for (let i = 0, len = content.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(content[i]);
    }
```

it prints all indexs [r e n e etc

if do foreach

```
content.forEach(function(content){
    console.log(content);
})
```

it throws error `content.forEach` is not a function

Comment: Running the foreach in the browser works fine. it prints out both values

Comment: Are you sure you've declared `content = ["renewel","payments"]` properly? When I run the foreach code along with the above line, it works properly. (I don't get an error.)

Comment: add `console.log(context)` before that line and you will likely know what is the problem.

Comment: Based on the context, it seems like you somehow made `content` a string rather than an array.  Is this your code **exactly** as written?

Comment: It worked fine for me: https://i.imgur.com/NCnL4ME.png

Comment: Yes it is exactly as it is written only things is i am getting as JSON that i have parsed and assign it to content variable

Comment: @hussain Can you include that as well? As it stands right now it's impossible to reproduce.

Comment: @hussain If `content` is parsed JSON, then this is not your code exactly as written.  Most likely you made a mistake in the parsing, but we can't know for sure unless you post that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine; it's very likely you've mutated content's type in some way at some point in your code. Ensure any functions you may be passing it (content) to aren't mutating the original array.

You might also consider using newer syntax, like:

`content.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
});`

or even

`content.forEach(item=> console.log(item));`

Two small things, by the way; there's no need to cache length in a `for` loop (JS engine does that for you), and I don't know if it matters or not... but you've misspelled 'renewal' ;)

Comment: You could.. but that also outputs the index and the whole array for each iteration.

Comment: I just did... I'm using Chrome's console :) Same thing in a Node 10 console.